# Add link to text within cell, not entire cell

Tags: python, hyperlink, openpyxl

Using Openpyxl, is there a way to create a link within a cell?

I tried:

```
worksheet['A1'].hyperlink = 'http://mypage.com'
```

However, this sets the entire cell of 'A1' to be a link.  I would like it to set the text within the cell to a link so that it looks like: [My page](http://mypage.com) in cell A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
wb = load_workbook("my_book.xlsx")
worksheet1 = wb.active()
cell_value = '=HYPERLINK("http://mypage.com", "My Page")'
worksheet1.cell(row=1, column=1, value=cell_value)
```

The important part of my example is that you can just set the value of the cell to excel's hyperlink function as a string.  The first parameter is the link and the second parameter is the text to display in the cell.

Comment: When I use this method, the text is indeed a link and not the cell.  However, it doesn't appear like a regular link (blue, underlined, etc.).  Is this a limitation of how cells are styled by Openpyxl?